# How to solve this linear second-order partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

So I first want to find the general solution for:

$2U_t+U_{xt}=0$ where $U=U(x,t)$

Once I have a general solution, I also want to find the solution for the following initial value problem:

$U(x,0)=0$  ,  $U_t(x,0)=e^{2x}$

So far, my best attempt has been as follows:

1) Integrate both sides with respect to $t$ to get:
$2U+U_x=f(x)$

2) Using integrating factor method:

$\partial/\partial x (Ue^{2x})=f(x)e^{2x}$

3) Integrate and solve for $U(x,t)$:

$U(x,t)=e^{-2x}\int f(x)e^{2x}dx$

Assuming everything I did here is correct, this seems to imply that $U$ is only a function of $x$.

But, this would disagree with the initial value problem, since $U_t(x,0)=e^{2x}$.

Am I missing something here?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure how you conclude the statement $U(x,t) =g(x)+h(t)$. Following, everything up to step 3, you have shown that $U$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking that I was integrating a function which was dependent on both $x$ and $t$, when in fact it only depends on $x$. I will edit this accordingly. Thank you.